# Почему слетают шрифты в Nuxtjs?

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js

В файле *app.scss* подключаю шрифты таким способом:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Hagrid';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Hagrid Trial Regular'), url('~assets/font/Hagrid/Hagrid-Regular-trial.woff') format('woff');
}
```

При ***npm run dev*** все работает и шрифты отображаются,
но при ***npm run build*** все шрифты слетают и не загружуются

*nuxt.config.js*

```
build: {
    optimizeCss: false,
    filenames: {
      app: ({ isDev }) => isDev ? '[name].js' : 'js/[contenthash].js',
      chunk: ({ isDev }) => isDev ? '[name].js' : 'js/[contenthash].js',
      css: ({ isDev }) => isDev ? '[name].css' : 'css/[contenthash].css',
      img: ({ isDev }) => isDev ? '[path][name].[ext]' : 'img/[contenthash:7].[ext]',
      font: ({ isDev }) => isDev ? '[path][name].[ext]' : 'fonts/[contenthash:7].[ext]',
      video: ({ isDev }) => isDev ? '[path][name].[ext]' : 'videos/[contenthash:7].[ext]'
    },
    extend(config, ctx) {
      config.module.rules.push({
        enforce: 'pre',
        test: /\.(js|vue)$/,
        loader: 'eslint-loader',
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        options: {
          fix: true
        }
      })
    },
    loaders: {
      cssModules: {
        modules: {
          localIdentName: "[hash:base64:6]",
        }
      }
    },
    ...(!isDev && {
      html: {
        minify: {
          collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
          decodeEntities: true,
          minifyCSS: true,
          minifyJS: true,
          processConditionalComments: true,
          removeEmptyAttributes: true,
          removeRedundantAttributes: true,
          trimCustomFragments: true,
          useShortDoctype: true
        }
      }
    }),
    splitChunks: {
      layouts: true,
      pages: true,
      commons: true
    },
    optimization: {
      minimize: !isDev
    },
    ...(!isDev && {
      extractCSS: {
        ignoreOrder: true
      }
    }),
    postcss: {
      plugins: {
        ...(!isDev && {
          cssnano: {
            preset: ['advanced', {
              autoprefixer: false,
              cssDeclarationSorter: false,
              zindex: false,
              discardComments: {
                removeAll: true
              }
            }]
          }
        })
      },
      ...(!isDev && {
        preset: {
          browsers: 'cover 99.5%',
          autoprefixer: true
        }
      }),

      order: 'cssnanoLast'
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

была причина вот в этом куске

```
  plugins: {
    ...(!isDev && {
      cssnano: {
        preset: ['advanced', {
          autoprefixer: false,
          cssDeclarationSorter: false,
          zindex: false,
          discardComments: {
            removeAll: true
          }
        }]
      }
    })
  },
```